# keep your login creadianls works after close of the app and the system in universal apps

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have developped a windows store app with C#,and I want to make my application keeps the login crediantials after the close of the application (like the Groove app after connexion and the close of the App,when I reopen it in an other time I get the application interface without putting login crediantials every time)
any explication in how to do that in universal apps please
thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution to all your problems: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227081

PasswordVault is the perfect place and the secure way to store your user credentials. It use the Windows Credential Manager and it allows you also to roam the credentials across devices, if this is the behavior you want to achieve.

Sample code:

```c
// Create a new credentials set
var passwordCredential = new PasswordCredential("MyAppName", "username", "password");

// Stores the PasswordCredential in the PasswordVault
var passwordVault = new PasswordVault();
passwordVault.Add(passwordCredential);

// To later retrieve the credentials
var credentials = passwordVault.Retrieve("MyAppName", "username");

// To populate the Password property in the PasswordCredential
credentials.RetrievePassword();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply @tommaso Scalici,should I put those lines in app.xaml??

Comment: Yes, depends on where you want to do login operations and where you acquire user credentials. Even the App.xaml codebehind is fine.
Don't worry where you initialize the PasswordVault because it always contains all the credentials for the user you previously stored.

Answer (score 0):

it's a very common scenario.
You must use Storage folder to save all the data.

I recommend you save your file in json, serialize and Deserialize the data.

with this approach you can save the credentials of the user and when the user will open the app again you will need to check if there is a previous saved data( the login credentials) if yes you can skip the login page and navigate to the main page

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files

Comment: thanks Sir RicardoPons for your reply,I will try your solution :)